# Harmony on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, ecmascript-harmony

I'd like to get a simple generator function working on Openshift Online PaaS. I followed the instructions at [nodejs-custom-version-openshift](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift) to run node 0.12 rather the default 0.10, and added a simple generator function to the bottom of `server.js`.

I added the `harmony` flag [as per instructed](http://www.zev23.com/2014/04/openshift-harmony-nodejs.html), and it works locally with `npm start` and `node server.js`. However on Openshift I get:

```
DEBUG: Program node --harmony server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node --harmony server.js'
/var/lib/openshift/0000000000700003a/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:33
function* idMaker(){
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Is there another, better way to use harmony/generators on Openshift?

Comment: Have you specified `"engines": {"node": ">= 0.12.0"},` in your `package.json`? Also try creating a file `.openshift/markers/NODEJS_VERSION` and put `0.12.5` in there

Comment: thanks @laggingreflex the [repo I cloned from](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift) includes the engines entry for 0.12. I added `.openshift/markers/NODEJS_VERSION` and put `0.12.5` but no joy. I think OS is using 0.12 successfully as the Jenkins build log includes "Node.js version 0.12.0 is already installed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me for not looking at the issues page for the Github repo of this [custom node version package](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/128-node-js-0-12), but [this comment](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/issues/2#issuecomment-140337668) solved it, by adding a line in `.openshift/lib/utils`. Perhaps this Q/A still useful to someone!